# Too many internal channel errors while using Channel API

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

We use Channel API in our Google App Engine application to send updates to our users. The code to send updates is something like this

```
for(String clientID: listOfClientID)
    channelService.sendMessage(new ChannelMessage(clientID, stringMessage));
```

Over the past few weeks, we've been getting too many exceptions in this method. We get around around 150 exceptions for a 8-hour peak usage period.

```
com.google.appengine.api.channel.ChannelFailureException: An internal channel error occured.
```

The loop can have 500-3000 iterations. Is it a problem when ChannelService tries to send a message to a channel that has been closed? If I remove closed channels from the list, will it completely solve the problem? Please note that this large number of exceptions have been a trend only in the past few weeks and we've been using Channel API for several months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was the server trying to send messages to channels that have expired. The error rate has gone down considerably when I made sure that doesn't happen anymore.